# how to find element by name using mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to get the title of an element that's already in the database. I am using `find()` to get the title but when I try to print it. I get an empty array which shouldn't be the case. here is the function that I am having a problem with. Thank you so much in advance!

**the function**

```
    ...
    posts.find({}, (err, foundPosts) => {
    console.log(foundPosts[0].title);
    if (foundPosts.length !== 0) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
            //i still have a problem here
            const postTitle = _.kebabCase(foundPosts[0].title);
            const postTil = _.upperFirst(postTitle);
            console.log(postTil);
            if (postTil === reqTitel) {
                console.log("true");
                res.render("posts", { foundPosts: foundPosts[0] });
            }
        }
    }
    });
});
```

**Here is the entire code**

I am only able to get the first title because I am using index[0]

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();
const _ = require("lodash");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
const items = [];
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb+srv://zaid:password@cluster0.3nbpg.mongodb.net/post", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("mongoDB connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({title: String, content: String});
const posts = mongoose.model("post", postsSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  posts.find({}, (err, foundPosts) => {
    if (foundPosts.length !== 0) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error line 23", err.message);
        res.render("laoding");
      } else {
        console.log("successful");
        res.render("index", {items: foundPosts});
      }
    }
  });
  // console.log(posts.find({title}));
});

app.get("/post", (req, res) => {
  res.render("post");
});

app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const content = req.body.content;

  const post = new posts({
    title,
    content,
  });
  post.save();
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/posts/:title", (req, res) => {
  var requstedTilte = _.kebabCase(req.params.title);
  var reqTitel = _.upperFirst(requstedTilte);
  console.log(reqTitel);

  posts.find({}, (err, foundPosts) => {
    console.log(foundPosts[0].title);
    if (foundPosts.length !== 0) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        //i still have a problem here
        const postTitle = _.kebabCase(foundPosts[0].title);
        const postTil = _.upperFirst(postTitle);
        console.log(postTil);
        if (postTil === reqTitel) {
          console.log("true");
          res.render("posts", {foundPosts: foundPosts[0]});
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: it's not quite clear what you're trying to do. You're saying you're using `find()` to get the title, but do you realize that you're actually searching _by_ title? Are you sure that the document with that title does exist in the database?

Comment: @AlexeyShchur, yes it's in the database, if  i try to find the title without any specific  filed like this `posts.find({}, (err, foundPosts) => { console.log(foundPosts[0].title); }` .  I am able to print the title this way but i don't know why it doesn't why i search by title!

Comment: Why are you using `_.kebabCase` and `_.upperFirst`? What is the title in DB and what does the url you using to get the post look like? Add the object from db and the url to your question. Don't post it as a comment.

Comment: @Molda the `_.kebabCase ` and `_.upperFirst` to match the url i am trying to reach. the title is "my first blog". I am updating the code. thank you!

Comment: If the title is `my first blog` then your code will never work. Even if the `req.params.title` would be `my first blog` the `_.kebabCase`  and `_.upperFirst` will turn it into `My-first-blog` and that is not the title you have in DB

Comment: @Molda. i did update the code. now i am able to get the first title because i am targeting index [0] but as i showed before searching using the title doesn't work! does that make sense ?

Comment: @Molda, i see. let me try and let you know. i have another question. is there a way i can get the index dynamically

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Also if you want to get just one post by title use `posts.findOne`.

Comment: @Molda can we have a chat ? and what i mean index dynamically is, that instead  of saying `foundPosts[0].title`, is there a way i can say `foundPosts.[index].title`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217867/discussion-between-molda-and-zaid).